# Method create and destroy doesn't work : ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, destroy

I am beginner on coding and on Ruby on rails.

I start to code an app to reference my favorite restaurants.
I start coding **my action on my Restaurant Controller** and the action **Index, Show and Update work.**
But I don't understand why **my method create and destroy don't work.**

- Data base : schema.rb :

```
  create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "price"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "website"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_restaurants_on_user_id"
  end
```

- Model : restaurant.rb :

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  CATEGORY = ['Gourmand', 'Healthy', 'Asiatique', 'Italien', 'Cuisine du monde', 'Traditionel',
              'Festive', 'Chic', 'Populaire', 'Fast-food', 'Casher', 'Halal', 'Vegan/Végétarien']

  PRICE = ['€', '€€', '€€€', '€€€€']

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :price, inclusion: { in: Restaurant::PRICE }, presence: true
  validates :category, inclusion: { in: Restaurant::CATEGORY }, presence: true
end
```

- Controller : restaurants_controller.rb

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @restaurant = Restaurant.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
    @restaurant.save!
    redirect_to restaurants_path(@restaurant), notice: 'new add'

    # if @restaurant.save
    #   redirect_to restaurants_path(@restaurant), notice: 'New restaurant added'
    # else
    #   render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    # end

  end
  def edit
  end

  def update
    @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
    redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant), notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.'
  end

  def destroy
    @restaurant.destroy
    redirect_to restaurants_path, status: :see_other
  end

  private

  def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(
      :name,
      :address,
      :category,
      :website,
      :price
    )
  end

  def set_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

- View new : new.html.erb :

```
<h1>Add a new restaurant </h1>
<%= render 'restaurants/form', restaurant: @restaurant %>
```

- View simple form : _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(restaurant) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :category, collection: Restaurant::CATEGORY%>
  <%= f.input :price, collection:Restaurant::PRICE %>
  <%= f.input :website%>
  <%= f.submit "#{ restaurant.persisted? ? 'Update' : 'Create' } Restaurant" %>
  <%#= link_to 'Back to restaurant', restaurants_path %>
<% end %>
```

I add Devise Gems by the way but I skip the authentification with a :

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

on my Restaurant Controller so it does not come from Devise.

Thank you :)

I check on my rails console : no restaurants created
When I put a '**raise**' in the action '**create**' just before my @restaurant.save, I can see on the params all the informations I added on my form.
But I don't know why it doesn't save my information and don't create the restaurant.

Comment: can you please add  `save!` and check what error is causing this.
Also add error in question.

Comment: Instead of using `save!` which is a bad crutch  use the [`debug` gem](https://github.com/ruby/debug) and set a breakpoint right after `if @restaurant.save`. If you look at `@restaurant.errors` it should tell you what validation errors occured. Looking at the logs will also tell you if Rails performed an INSERT query and if it was rolled back.

Comment: `save!` should really only be used when you really need an exception to be raised like inside of a transaction - as a method of debugging its kind of stupid as you should be providing the user feedback on [what validations failed in the form anyways](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views). SimpleForm should do this for you.